# Compile error: ‘Init’ is not a member of ‘ros’

Tags: ros, tutorial, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04, ROS Hydro

Workspace:

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH 

/home/kirill/dev/rosbook:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

Created ROS pack:

```
roscd chapter2_tutorials/src/
ls

bin  build  CMakeLists.txt  include  lib  mainpage.dox  Makefile  manifest.xml  src
```

Test ROS Package has two source files:

```
cd src
ls

example1_a.cpp  example1_b.cpp
```

example1_a.cpp:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::Init(argc, argv, "example1_a");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_
msgs::String>("message", 1000);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    std_msgs:String msg;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << " I am the example_a node ";
    msg.data = ss.str();
    //
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

example1_b.cpp:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::Init(argc, argv, "example1_b");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subcribe("message", 1000, chatterCallback);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
rosed chapter2_tutorials CMakeLists.txt
   
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})

rosbuild_add_executable(example1_a src/example1_a.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(example1_b src/example1_b.cpp)
```

Making package:

```
kirill@kirill-Aspire-E1-571G:~/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials$ rosmake chapter2_tutorials
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['chapter2_tutorials']                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/kirill/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140607-195627                                                       
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['chapter2_tutorials'] to:
['chapter2_tutorials']                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg                                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                                                                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp                                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> console_bridge [ make ]                                                                                                
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy                                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp                                                    
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                                                                                            
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< console_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package console_bridge
 No Makefile in package console_bridge                            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                                                                    
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation                
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang cpp_common: 0.0 sec ] [ rosgraph: 0.0 sec ]                   [ 4 Active 8/25 Complete ]
 No Makefile in package roslang                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib                                                    
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph                                              
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp                                              
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime                                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                                                                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs                                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                 
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild                                              
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp                                                    
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                                         
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy                                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> chapter2_tutorials [ make ]                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesapter2_tutorials: 3.8 sec ]                                                                 [ 1 Active 24/25     Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  [ 50%] [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example1_b.dir/src/example1_b.cpp.o
  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/example1_a.dir/src/example1_a.cpp.o
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_b.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_b.cpp:12:3: error: ‘Init’ is not a member of ‘ros’
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_b.cpp:14:27: error: ‘class ros::NodeHandle’ has no member     named ‘subcribe’
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_b.cpp:14:19: warning: unused variable ‘sub’ [-Wunused-    variable]
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:7:3: error: ‘Init’ is not a member of ‘ros’
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:9:44: error: ‘std_’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:9:34: error: parse error in template argument list
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:10:30: error: no matching function for call to     
‘ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const char [8], int)’
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:10:30: note: candidates are:
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:236:15: note: template<class M> ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const     string&, uint32_t, bool)
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:300:13: note: template<class M> ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const     string&, uint32_t, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const SubscriberStatusCallback&, const VoidConstPtr&, bool)
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:14:14: error: ‘String’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:14:14: note: suggested alternative:
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/std_msgs/String.h:80:52: note:   ‘std_msgs::String’
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:14:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘msg’
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:17:5: error: ‘msg’ was not declared in this scope
  /home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/src/example1_a.cpp:14:5: warning: label ‘std_msgs’ defined but not used [-    Wunused-label]
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/example1_b.dir/src/example1_b.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example1_b.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/example1_a.dir/src/example1_a.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example1_a.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kirill/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials/build'
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package chapter2_tutorials written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/kirill/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140607-195627/chapter2_tutorials/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< chapter2_tutorials [FAIL] [ 3.77 seconds ]                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package chapter2_tutorials. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                           
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 25 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/kirill/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140607-195627                                                                            
kirill@kirill-Aspire-E1-571G:~/dev/rosbook/chapter2_tutorials$
```

I can't build tutorial node because of error:

```
error: ‘Init’ is not a member of ‘ros’
```

Could anyone give a clue how to solve this issue?

Regards,
Kirill

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173004/compile-error:-%E2%80%98init%E2%80%99-is-not-a-member-of-%E2%80%98ros%E2%80%99/) by [Robotics010](https://answers.ros.org/users/12336/robotics010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros::init` not `ros::Init`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robotics010](https://answers.ros.org/users/12336/robotics010/) on 2014-06-07**:
hi, dornhege!

Yeah, you are right. I should to code with more care and attention.

There were a several errors with literal errors.

This resource was helpful for me - http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle-members.html

Or we can just google this "class ros::NodeHandle" to found out members with right case sensitive.

Thanks!

Regards,
Kirill.